# reescale html text when the window size is changed

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have the following standard .Rmd file.

````
---
title: "STARTSTARTSTART &emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp; ENDENDEND"
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%d de %B, %Y')`"
output:
  html_document
---



This is an [R Markdown](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com) Notebook. When you execute code within the notebook, the results appear beneath the code. 

Try executing this chunk by clicking the *Run* button within the chunk or by placing your cursor inside it and pressing *Ctrl+Shift+Enter*. 

```{r}
plot(cars)
```

Add a new chunk by clicking the *Insert Chunk* button on the toolbar or by pressing *Ctrl+Alt+I*.

When you save the notebook, an HTML file containing the code and output will be saved alongside it (click the *Preview* button or press *Ctrl+Shift+K* to preview the HTML file).

The preview shows you a rendered HTML copy of the contents of the editor. Consequently, unlike *Knit*, *Preview* does not run any R code chunks. Instead, the output of the chunk when it was last run in the editor is displayed.
````

We can see the output in full window form:

[image: output1]

When we reduce the window size, the plot scales down so it still fits, while the title and text letters keep the same size and the gap between words start to decrease to a point where a new line is created to accommodate it all.

[image: output2]

Is there any way I can make the title, or any other HTML text, to behave like the plot, keeping the structure and scaling down when the size of the page is reduced?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use custom css styles to achieve scaling:

````
---
---
    ```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
    ```
# Custom CSS
    ```{css, echo=FALSE}
h1 {
  font-size: 5.9vw;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 3.0vh;
}
p {
  font-size: 2vmin;
}
    ```

## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:

    ```{r cars}
summary(cars)
    ```

## Including Plots

You can also embed plots, for example:

    ```{r pressure, echo=FALSE}
plot(pressure)
    ```

Note that the `echo = FALSE` parameter was added to the code chunk to prevent printing of the R code that generated the plot.
````

Look at https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/html-css.html and https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/ for more details concerning inclusion of CSS in RMd and Viewport based scaling in CSS.

[image: Big Window]

[image: Small Window]

If we want to fix the width of the output to a page size we can do so by fixing the width of the main container. Then we should be able to use manual linebreaks at the positions we need.

````
---
title: "STARTSTARTSTART &emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp; ENDENDEND"
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%d de %B, %Y')`"
output:
  html_document
---
<!--- Change width options to apppropiate values for your desired page size-->
<style type="text/css">
.main-container {
  width: 20cm;
  max-width: 20cm;
  min-width: 20cm;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
</style>

    ```{r setup, include=FALSE}
    knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
    ```
## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:

    ```{r cars}
    summary(cars)
    ```

## Including Plots

You can also embed plots, for example:

    ```{r pressure, echo=FALSE}
plot(pressure)
    ```

Note that the `echo = FALSE` parameter was added to the code chunk to prevent printing of the R code that generated the plot.
````

Comment: Even when you do this, the line breaks still happen in different points of the text when the window size is changed. How could I fix the format for the text, so it doesn't happen?

Comment: You would have to put all text in `divs` with appropriate properties then, but I'm not sure HTML is the right output format for you, if you want to achieve this behaviour. Why not use a PDF if you want basically static output anyway?

Comment: For PDF output I am pretty sure I would have to install some Latex programs, but I can't because I want to run this report in my company. Another solution would be to print this HTML to PDF but I am not succeeding in doing that, keeping the same format as the HTML file...

Comment: I do know that print to PDF from HTML is actually one of the best ways to keep the integrity of the Rmarkdown rendered document, but like you said, you wouldn't be able to get the responsiveness of the HTML. that Viewpoint link was very awesome, I will have to check that out too.

Comment: I've though about this some more @daniellga: I think by adjusting the width parameters of the main container you could achieve the behaviour you want. I've updated the answer with the relevant section on top of the Markdown code.

Comment: adding the custom CSS `.fluid-row .title {font-size: 5.9vw;}` allows the title text size to be responsive to screen size

Comment: @Julian_Hn that was wonderful, thank you. I am a completely CSS ignorant.